# JPA/Hibernate: How to scan particular package in Persistence.xml in place of giving single entity name?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have 10 entities in package:

```
 com.paka.maka.raka
```

I have 5 entities in package

```
com.paka
```

I only want to scan 10 entities in first package name.

Is it mandatory to name whole classes or is there way to give package name only to scan in Persistance.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="IntegratorMasterdataPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" >
            <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@dat-esb-orat:1521/rator_test" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="DATA" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="264rcxx" />
<!--QA          <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="emifuqqgqn5" /> -->
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
<!--            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" /> -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Comment: As long as you want to use persistence.xml it's not possible

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure it will work, but you can use:

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.paka.maka.raka"/>
```

In your entityManagerFactory bean declaration

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855487/remove-the-uses-of-class-tag-in-persistence-xml-hibernate?rq=1)